# Redefine brace math delimiter

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, mathdesign

I'm trying to achieve left and right brace math delimiters, the ones that LaTeX has as standard, since I don't really like the ones that `mathdesign` font has. Is there some command such as `\definemathdelimiter` to redefine it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{abraces}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\phi(z) =
    \left\{\begin{tabular}{cl}
    $ 2\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} + x}\right) $ & if  $ x>0  \text{ or }  y \neq 0 $\\
    $ \pi $ & if  $ x<0\text{ and }  y = 0 $ \\
    Does not exist & if  $ x=0\text{ and } y = 0 $
    \end{tabular}\right.\
\end{equation*}

    \[
    \aunderbrace{\text{The desired delimiter}}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is also \lbrace and \rbrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the original definitions from `fontmath.ltx`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}%
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}
   {\mathclose}{cmsymbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}
   {\mathopen}{cmsymbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}

% Charter version, just to show the difference
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfoo}
   {\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{largesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfoo}
   {\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{largesymbols}{"08}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{abraces}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\left\{\Biggl\{\biggl\{\Bigl\{\bigl\{\{\rule{0pt}{5ex}\}\bigr\}\Bigr\}\biggr\}\Biggr\}\right\} \\
\left\lfoo\Biggl\lfoo\biggl\lfoo\Bigl\lfoo\bigl\lfoo\lfoo\rule{0pt}{5ex}\rfoo\bigr\rfoo\Bigr\rfoo\biggr\rfoo\Biggr\rfoo\right\rfoo 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't recommend this for two reasons:

- (objective reason) This will waste two precious symbols fonts.
- (personal opinion) The font designers spent some time on their job. The `charter` braces *definitely*  harmonize better with the rest of the font. Mixing symbols from different fonts seldom improves the appearance of a document.

Comment: Of course, the font is awesome and I appreciate the work of the designer, they make LaTeX better every day. I want it for an specific and small particular case (the example of the photo was just to illustrate my needs). Thanks a lot for you response.

Comment: @Martín I didn't want to soud too harsh. There are users who try to build up a "custom font" by mixing every glyph they like, and that's what I wanted to discourage. Note also that what you describe as "the desired delimiter" in your question is a strange mix too: if you zoom in, you'll see that the ends are from `charter`, while the lines are normal. I believe `abraces` doesn't work best with fonts different from CM.